# Specify X-Axis Category in Series Data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to implement a stacked bar graph and I would like to understand if there is anyway that we can specify the category along with the data point in series.

I have Categories as :

```
xAxis: {
categories: ['DEV', 'TEST', 'Stage']
},
```

Series data:

```
series: [{
name: 'Severity-1',
data: [['TEST',20]]
},{
name: 'Severity-2',
data: [['TEST',20]]
}]
```

In above snippet I am trying to add a point value '30' to 'TEST' category but when I load the graph it shows up under 'DEV' category.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/G5S9L/1/

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try:

```
{"xAxis": { "type" : "category" .... } ... }
```

It should get category from your data.

Answer (score 2):

==== **V3+** ====

Set `xAxis.type = "category"` with `xAxis.uniqueNames = true`.

You read more about [`type`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type) and [`uniqueNames`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.uniqueNames) options.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6rj3xf0z/1/

==== **PRE v3** ====

You need to use category index instead of category name, so the proper example will be:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Severity-1',
  data: [[1,20]] //0-DEV, 1-TEST, 2-Stage
},{
  name: 'Severity-2',
  data: [[1,20]]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel, it worked for me but I ran into another issue where my xAxis is showing numbers instead of the labels. I have like 20 categories listed and on the chart only a few get listed and then numbers like 12.5 13.5 show up on the xAxis. How do I force the charts to show only labels from categories?

Comment: Make sure you have proper indexes (0, 1, 2 .. n-1) where n is number of categories from: `xAxis: {
categories: ['DEV', 'TEST', 'Stage'] // n = 3
},`

Comment: I verified that and the index values are correctly formed, there are two things which are noticeable: 1) the series data is like -[0,1],[2,10],[1,5], meaning it is not ordered that's mainly because how the backend generates the data but I soon as I order the data the labels show up. 2) This is not happening where I have more than 40 categories.

Comment: 1) Data have to be sorted, with sorted data it works properly, see: http://jsfiddle.net/HsLCn/2/ 2) Data is sorted I guess? Btw, I can see issue with stack labels, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2325).

Answer (score -2):

Hey Vipul Do you want something like this ? Please check the link below for the code.

```
series: [{
     name: 'Severity-1',
     data: [['TEST',20]]
     },{
     name: 'Severity-2',
     data: [['TEST',20]]
 }]
```

[CHECK EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karamjeetpnf/zTmD2/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but what I want to achieve is to plot the bar chart using the series data which should include category and value for y-axis

Comment: He asked WITHOUT category.